# Drupal Display suites

Tags: drupal

I hope im not being daft here, but ive recently installd display suites (6.x-1.3) and ive been watching a few tutorials and on some of those tutorials they have the following, which I dont have.

1. STyles ( I assume this is because I have not yet defined any styles in my theme ?)
2. Region to Block ? ( is this perhaps a seperate module I need to install)

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ive installed Display suites, and in most of the tutorials I watch, they have another button ontop called "region to Block" I dont seem top have that button, nor do I have the styles button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of Dipslay Suite have these functionality (6.x-1.4).

You still have to enable the plugins by going there :
admin/build/ds/nd/plugins